# Copy Android SDK

Tags: android

I want to copy the Android SDK folder from one PC to multiple PCs (without installation) and test one android application in android emulator. Everything works fine. But I need to know whether copy paste of android SDK is allowed or is there any license restriction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is allowed, but it would be better if you follow their procedure so tg

Answer (score 0):

It's allowed. You just need to add or set proper SDK location path after pasting SDK in your specific folder.

If using Linux or Ubuntu make sure that location has access permission.